# Oracle reproducing timeouts IDLE_TIME/CONNECT_TIME

Tags: php, oracle, timeout, oracle-xe, oci8

I need some help with oracle settings to reproduce some issues we're having and to clarify, I'm not a oracle expert at all - no experience with it.

I've managed to installed oracle-xe(because it's easiest & smallest) and got our software running on it.

Now, reports say, that the connection in some some production setups time out(long running scripts/programs) and are not reconnected (not even throwing exceptions). 
So that's what I'm trying to reproduce.

After some browsing around on the internet I found that running these queries should limit my connection & idle time to 1 minute:

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT IDLE_TIME 1;
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT CONNECT_TIME 1;
ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_LIMIT = TRUE;
```

Results in:
    SQL> select * from user_resource_limits where resource_name in ('IDLE_TIME','CONNECT_TIME');

```
RESOURCE_NAME                    LIMIT
-------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
IDLE_TIME                        1
CONNECT_TIME                     1
```

After that I made a simple php script 'test.php', it runs a query - sleeps, and runs a new query.

```
require_once('our software');
$account1 = findAccount('email1@example.com');
sleep(100);
$account2 = findAccount('email2@example.com');
```

Isn't this supposed to time out?

Some extra details about what software I'm running:

- Centos 5
- Oracle XE
- php 5.3.5
- using oci8(not pdo)

Comment: Is it possible that findAccount is opening and closing a connection each time and your not actually using the same connection to experience the time out?